# Progress bar component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, haml

So I have a progressbar component and when the value reaches 100% I'd like to change the color or green. This is being handled using:
`ng-class="{'progress-100': progress.value == 100}"`

In my view I have `%atom-progressbar`

*I'm confused on how to evaluate whether or not to add a class in link*

This is what I have so far:

```js
app = angular.module('appname')

pattern =
  name: 'atomProgressbar'

# ---------------------------------------------------------- #
# Logo

app.directive 'atomProgressbar', ($patterns, $atomicService) ->
  template: """
  <progress ng-class="{'progress-100': progress.value == 100}" id='progress-bar' max='100' value='20'></progress>
  """
  scope: $patterns.NGBindings(pattern.bindings)
  link: ($scope) ->
    $atomicService.processBindings(pattern, $scope)



# EXAMPLE ->
# %atom-progress{:max => "100", :value => "0"}

export default pattern
```

```css
// # ========= --- Progressbar Styles --- ========== # \\

atom-progressbar {
  appearance: none !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

progress {
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: get-color('light-grey');
  width: 100%;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: get-color('warning');
  width: 100%;

}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: get-color('warning');
  transition: all .7s;
}

progress::-moz-progress-value {
  background-color: get-color('warning');
  transition: all .7s;
}

.progress-100 {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.progress-100::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.progress-100::-moz-progress-value {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
 %atom-progressbar
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand your question properly.but I think you can use .alternate class in your code. 
for example consider following code snippet.

```
if (progress === 0) {
    progressbar.classList.toggle('alternate')
    // ...
}
```

and then you can set the color of your choice.